# Javascript click and problems with string

Tags: string, delphi

I need the string recognizes the comma

```
var
  script2 : string;
begin
  script2 := 'javascript:doSubmit(13,'S', 'S');'
  ExecuteScript(webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2, script2, 'javascript');
end;
```

however I am getting the following error message

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: From the help, "Two sequential apostrophes in a quoted string denote a single character", so  `script2 := 'javascript:doSubmit(13,''S'', ''S'');`

Comment: @DavidA, good catch. Please put it as an answer so OP can accept it (and others see it's been answered).

Comment: `script2 := 'javascript:doSubmit(13, "S", "S");'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is due to the embedded apostrophes (single quotes) in your string. From the help, "Two sequential apostrophes in a quoted string denote a single character", so your code should be:

```
script2 := 'javascript:doSubmit(13, ''S'', ''S'')';
```